# PHP Form Data Validation is not working

Tags: php

Hi I'm trying to do a form with data validation before writing into database. But im not sure why the data validation is not working. Below is my codes

filename: bookoffer.php

```
$NameErr = $EmailErr = $DescriptionErr = ""; 
//$Name = $Email = $Description;

        if (isset($_POST['Submit']))
            {        
       $errors = array();
            if (empty($_POST['Name']))
                {
                $NameErr = "**Name is required**";
                }
                else
                    {
                        $Name = ($_POST['Name']);
                        //check if name only contain letter and white space
                        if (!preg_match("/^[a-zA-Z ]*$/",$Name))
                            {
                            $NameErr = "**Only letters and white space allowed**";
                            }
                    }



        if (empty($_POST['Email']))
        {
            $EmailErr = "**Email is required**";
        }
        else
            {
                $Email = ($_POST['Email']);;
                //check if e-mail address is well-formed
                if (!filter_var($Email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL))
                    {
                    $EmailErr = "**Invalid email format**";
                    }
            }


        if (empty($_POST['Description']))
        {
            $Description = "**Description is required**";
        }
        else
            {
            $Description = ($_POST['Description']);
            }

     }  
    //if(count($errors)==0)

        include 'database_connect.php';  //make database connection

        $Name = $_POST['Name'];
        $Email = $_POST['Email'];
        $Description = $_POST['Description'];      

        $sql = "INSERT INTO books_offer (Name, Email, Description) values ('$Name', '$Email', '$Description')";
        $redirect = true;
        header('Location: Thank_you.php');        
        mysqli_query($conn, $sql) or die (mysqli_error($conn));
        mysqli_close($conn);

?>
```

Here is the html file which is calling for bookoffer.php

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>  
<html>
<head>
<style>
.error {color: #FF0000;}
</style>
</head>

    <body>

        <h2>Please Offer Your Book</h2>
        <form id="bookoffer" method="post" action="bookoffer.php" > 
        <p><span class="error"> <font color="red">*required field.</font></span></p>

            Name<font color="red">*</font> <input type="text" name="Name" >
            <span class="error"> <?php echo $NameErr;?></span>
            <br></br>

            Email<font color="red">*</font> <input type="text" name="Email" >
            <span class="error"> <?php echo $EmailErr;?></span>
            <br></br>

            Description<font color="red">*</font><textarea name ="Description" rows="5" cols="40" ></textarea>
            <span class="error"> <?php echo $DescriptionErr;?></span>
            <br></br>
                <input type="submit" name="submit_form" value="Submit" /> 
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Below is not your codes

Comment: where's the HTML form for this? you need to edit your question to contain it. We don't know if that is at fault or not. If you left the question, then nobody will be able to help, unless they do a complete rewrite and sincerely doubt they will wait till you come back and/or update your question.

Comment: `$NameErr = $EmailErr = $DescriptionErr = ""; `  Um.. what ??

Comment: @Duane Lortie it's setting multiple variables to an empty string.

Comment: why your variable name is in pascal case ? To my opinion variable name should be in camel case or underscore case, it provides better readability.

Comment: @Steve 6  OK.. I figured that's what it did, just never seen it done that way. Back in my day ..............

Answer (score 0):

You're not populating your `$errors` array so the if statement you've commented out will always be `true`. You are storing your errors in individual variables. One option would be to change

```
$errors = array();
```

to

```
$errors = false;
```

then, when you are setting the error variables add a line to each one to set `$errors` to `true`, one example,

```
if (empty($_POST['Name']))
{
   $NameErr = "**Name is required**";
   $errors = true; // this line added
}
```

You can now update your commented out if statement to

```
if ($errors) {
```